# how to display f-curves that are not showing

Tags: graph-editor, fcurves, emission

When i insert a keyframe to the emission strength of material "light_red" in image 1(yellow in the bottom right), a keyframe is added to the graph editor

image 1:
[image]

However when i add a keyframe to material "light_blue" in image 2, no keyframes are added. Furthermore, i cannot even see the graph of all the keyframes even after selecting the object. This is perplexing for me, as the object still goes through the colour change as I had input but i am unable to see the graph editor.

image 2:
[image]

How do i get blender to display the missing curves in image 2 so that I can start adjusting the shape of it?

Comment: Try to press A - Select All and than press Home key to View Selected. If it doesn't help please share your blend just with your two lights. Thank you